# Сервис API для Angular

Tags: api, javascript, angularjs

Использую вот такой шаблон [angular-boilerplate](https://github.com/galkinrost/angular-boilerplate) и пытаюсь написать API (factory или service) пробовал на $resource и на $http но все время натыкаюсь на проблему что возвращается не объект а что то не понятное для меня)

AngularJS v1.2.16

(angular изучаю 2 недели)

есть ли возможность собрать такой сервис чтоб при его подключении в контроллер, я бы писал что то типа этого API.get('') или API.post({}), а возвращался бы сразу json;

СЕРВИС

```
define(function (require) {
require("services/_module");
var angular = require("angular");
angular.module("App.services")
    .service('API', function () {
        this.get = function (query) {
            var url = 'http://api.localhost/';
            // получаем query равный NEGASH;
            // и делаем GET запрос на http://api.localhost/NEGASH;
            // и тут волшебство с .success и .then 
            return json;
        };
        this.post = function (query) {
            var url = 'http://localhost/';
            // получаем query равный {id:12};
            // и делаем POST запрос на http://api.localhost/;
            // и тут волшебство с .success и .then 
            return json;
        };
    });
});
```

КОНТРОЛЛЕР

```
define(function (require) {
require("modules/first/controllers/_module");
var angular = require("angular");
angular.module("First.controllers")
    .controller("first.ctrl",
        ["$scope","API",
            function ($scope, API) {
                $scope.profile = API.get('NEGASH');
                console.log($scope.profile);
                // нормальный объект с которым можно работать (for(), .length)
                $scope.some_info = API.post({id:12});
                console.log($scope.some_info); 
                // нормальный объект с которым можно работать (for(), .length)
            }]);
});
```

> ну и конечно если какие то ошибки в
> запросе обрабатывать их в API в
> контроллер **строго возвращать json**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите синхронные запросы что-ли ?

лучше сделайте модель и в коллбэке устанавливайте в ней значения. типа

```
$scope.myModel={};
API.get('NEGASH','myModel',$scope);
```

в сервисе в колбэке пишите что-то типа

```
this.get = function (query,model,scope) { 
    $http.get(query).then(function(result){scope[model]=result.data});
}
```

[демо](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqbsxU2YbN3DgIYpN6qB?p=preview)

Comment: Понял) но это такой костылинг (

Comment: где костылинг ? А как вы себе представляли ? return из асинхронной функции ? может есть и поизящнее решение, я в ангуляре тоже не шибко силен, но в javascript всё асинхронное делается примерно так. щас я пример попробую доделать.

Comment: Я просто уже попробовал, и вот я то как раз не силен в тонкостях возврата из ajax запросов (помню пол года назад та-же проблема у меня выскакивала в jquery & backbone там решалось через  `var self = this;`)

Comment: см пример, все очень просто.

Comment: $scope.myModel={id: 'loading'};
API.get('NEGASH.json','myModel',$scope);
console.log($scope.myModel); // Object {id: 'loading'}

хочу `Object {"id":"Hello World from json"}`

Comment: в следующей строчке не получится, сделайте [$watch](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqbsxU2YbN3DgIYpN6qB?p=preview)

ещё вариант, [возвращать то от чего можно сделать then](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cv5I1RBhYg0RWQBdRLQB?p=preview) по вкусу в общем и зависит от задач.

Comment: Задача в том что я не хочу использовать `.then()` в контроллере
хочу только

$scope.myModel={id: 'loading'};


API.get('NEGASH.json','myModel',$scope);


console.log($scope.myModel);

В этом вся проблема, только `API.get('');` и все

(может подключить jquery в сервис?)

Comment: ну поведение js от вашего желания не зависит, наверное можно синхронно сделать ([$http не позволит](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L64)), но это еще больший костыль. jQuery по умолчанию тоже делает запросы асинхронно. Вообще вопрос - чем вас не устраивает асинхронное выполнение, что за такая суперзадача для которой это критично ? (мне в жизни только пару раз приходилось делать запрос синхронно, да и то потом я понял, что не нужно было).